# Using the leak program with the iphone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am trying to run the memory leak program in conjunction with my iphone device.  The program says that there are leaks however it doesn't give me details.

GeneralBlock-32 No stack trace available.

How can I set up the leak program so it actually works with my iphone to give detailed information like it does in the simulator.

Comment: What build profile are you using? Debug, Release, or one of your own? If it's a custom build profile, are you stripping debugging symbols?

Comment: iPhone device 3.1 base sdk... is there a place to look to see if the debug symbols are stripped?

Comment: I see the strip symbols checkbox is not checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running in Release mode, the compiler will not generate any debug symbols to map the calls back to your code.

if this is the case, changing your build type to Debug mode will provide you with more information about the leaking area of your application.

I have also noticed that the Frameworks tend to have memory leaks of their own, so it could be a leak from the framework.